# How to select rows based on two columns creating an identifier and the max date

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, distinct, inventory

I have six columns.  One of the six columns I created myself.  It is two of the columns put together to create an identifier column.  I want to select only the max date row for each distinct combination of the identifier column.  When I omit the quantity column, I get the expected number of rows.  However, once I add in quantity it gives me rows I don't expect.  How do I select only the max date rows for each distinct occurrence of my Identifier column?

For example, when I run this query...

```
Select 
 Distinct(L.ItemNo+' 'L.Lot) as Identifier
 ,Max(L.PostingDate)
 ,L.ItemNo
 ,L.Description
 ,L.Quantity
 ,L.Lot
From dbo.JournalLine L
Groupy by
 L.ItemNo
 ,L.Lot
 ,L.Description
 ,L.Quantity
```

I get the below results.  The row here that I am not expecting is the row with 45 Apples.

| Identifier | PostingDate | ItemNo | Description | Quantity | Lot |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I123 LOT123 | 2021-06-01 | I123 | Celery | 79 | L123 |
| I456 LOT456 | 2021-06-01 | I456 | Carrot | 25 | L456 |
| I456 LOT654 | 2021-06-01 | I654 | Carrot | 21 | L654 |
| I789 LOT789 | 2021-05-28 | I789 | Apple | 45 | L789 |
| I789 LOT789 | 2021-06-01 | I789 | Apple | 38 | L789 |
| I789 LOT555 | 2021-06-01 | I789 | Apple | 11 | L555 |

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_, and belongs to `SELECT DISTINCT` - which applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses and simply write `Select Distinct L.ItemNo+' 'L.Lot as Identifier, ...` to make code less confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions `MAX()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` to get the values of `PostingDate` and `Quantity` respectively of the row with the latest `PostingDate`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       ItemNo + ' ' + Lot AS Identifier,
       MAX(PostingDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo, Lot, Description) AS PostingDate,
       ItemNo,
       Description,
       FIRST_VALUE(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ItemNo, Lot, Description ORDER BY PostingDate DESC) AS Quantity,
       Lot
FROM dbo.JournalLine
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The GROUP BY clause will gather all of the rows together that contain data in the specified columns (here the GroupBy operation is performed on columns `L.ItemNo`, `L.Lot`, `L.Description` and `L.Quantity`) and will allow aggregate functions to be performed on the one or more columns( Here the aggregation is done on `L.PostingDate`).

So each record with a distinct combination of the group by columns i.e `L.ItemNo`, `L.Lot`, `L.Description` and `L.Quantity` will come along with the aggregation on the duplicate combinations of it. For instance, considering your example: -

Let us assume that you have below records in your table:-

```
Identifier  PostingDate ItemNo  Description Quantity    Lot
I789 LOT789 2021-05-27  I789    Apple       45          L789
I789 LOT789 2021-05-29  I789    Apple       38          L789
I789 LOT789 2021-05-25  I789    Apple       45          L789
I789 LOT789 2021-05-28  I789    Apple       45          L789
I789 LOT789 2021-06-01  I789    Apple       38.         L789
I789 LOT555 2021-06-01  I789    Apple       11.         L555
```

So when you do a group by on `Identifier`, `ItemNo`, `Description`, `Quantity` and `Lot`, SQL will understand that you want to do a logical grouping of these columns and it will divide data and understand it as below:-

```
-- Group 1
Identifier  PostingDate ItemNo  Description Quantity    Lot
I789 LOT789 2021-05-27  I789    Apple       45          L789
I789 LOT789 2021-05-25  I789    Apple       45          L789
I789 LOT789 2021-05-28  I789    Apple       45          L789

-- Group 2
Identifier  PostingDate ItemNo  Description Quantity    Lot
I789 LOT789 2021-05-29  I789    Apple       38          L789
I789 LOT789 2021-06-01  I789    Apple       38.         L789

-- Group 3
Identifier  PostingDate ItemNo  Description Quantity    Lot
I789 LOT555 2021-06-01  I789    Apple       11.         L555
```

Now when you have any aggregate function run on these records on some particular column, it will try to run the aggregate function for each logical grouping it has encountered ( There are 3 in this case as we saw above)

So in our case, the aggregate function is `Max(L.PostingDate)` which will select the record with the maximum date for each group it has identified till now like below:-

```
-- Group 1
Identifier  PostingDate ItemNo  Description Quantity    Lot
I789 LOT789 2021-05-28  I789    Apple       45          L789

-- Group 2
Identifier  PostingDate ItemNo  Description Quantity    Lot
I789 LOT789 2021-06-01  I789    Apple       38.         L789

-- Group 3
Identifier  PostingDate ItemNo  Description Quantity    Lot
I789 LOT555 2021-06-01  I789    Apple       11.         L555
```

And now finally it combines all records and shows the result as below:-

```
-- Final Ouput
Identifier  PostingDate ItemNo  Description Quantity    Lot
I789 LOT789 2021-05-28  I789    Apple       45          L789
I789 LOT789 2021-06-01  I789    Apple       38.         L789
I789 LOT555 2021-06-01  I789    Apple       11.         L555
```

This is how `group by` functions, so in your case, if you don't want the group by to happen on `quantity` columns, you can simply remove it from select query as well as groupBy, or else if you include the `quantity` column to group by it will keep printing the records with the distinct column combination.

Answer (score 1):

you can use window function:

```
select * from (
  select * , row_number() over (partition by ItemNo,Lot order by PostingDate desc) rn
  from dbo.JournalLine
) l
where rn = 1
```